# Wordpress: How to integrate Find Nearest Shop function

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Firstly thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

I have a project where I have integrate a find nearest location function on a Wordpress website. The functionality should work as:

A user inserts their postcode into the search bar, and the results shown are shops which are nearest to their postcode.

Has anyone done anything like this before and if so do you have any recommendations on plugins or tutorials which could possibly help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I found a suitable plugin for the job:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/gwebpro-store-locator/

There are many plugins out there with the same functionality, but I chose this one.
I edited the plugin heavily to get it to work how I want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are looking is basically radius search for given zip code. I will suggest you to go through with this nice article to get start and complete your task.

https://www.dougv.com/2009/03/27/getting-all-zip-codes-in-a-given-radius-from-a-known-point-zip-code-via-php-and-mysql/